# How to animate rotate around center in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

When you use one of the handle bars to rotate an object in fabricjs it will rotate the object around center. However, when using

```
tri.animate('angle', 45, {
  onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)
});
```

It will rotate around the top-left corner. How to rotate around center just like with the handle bar?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QQ6eA/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add:

```
originX: 'center',
originY: 'center',
```

to your triangle creation code.

Comment: be careful about this though; doing this changes the `top` and `left` behavior also .. if you expect your image to be at `obj.top=0` and `obj.left=0` - changing the originX/Y will offset the `left` and `top` values to half-width and half-height respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you rotate an image with his default origin, this will do it around top left corner. We don't want to set the origin of the image on the center all the time, because it will affect all the functionalities (for example, its left and top positions).
So, we can set the origin to center when we need it and then set it again to the top-left corner and still use all the others functionalities normally.

```
const target = canvas.getActiveObject(); //or your target
const angleValue = 10; //your angle
target._setOriginToCenter();
target.set('angle', angleValue).setCoords();
target._resetOrigin();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: sorry about that, i saw myself involved in this problem and just post the solution when found it on GitHub! also im not good at English. Wish it helps better now!